# How do I enter multiple characters in TextBox1_Change

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I need to enter multiple characters into an ActiveX textbox in PowerPoint before the marco fires. Current macro fires as each character is typed.

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
   IF TextBox1.Value = "18" then
       MsgBox "You have entered 18"
   End If
End Sub
```

Previous attempts had failed so I had to add a `CommandButton` that would trigger the actions after all the characters were typed in the text box, however it is cumbersome to type and click to perform tasks. So it would be even better if the Macro would be triggered after hitting the Enter/Return key after the data required was entered. I have tried `KeyPress` and `KeyDown` and i.e.

```
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyDown(KeyCode As Integer, Shift As Integer)
    If KeyCode = vbKeyReturn Then
        MsgBox "hello"
    End If
End Sub
```

but that code gave me a compile error:

> Procedure declaration does not match description of event or procedure having the same name.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the LostFocus event would be more useful. Assuming that TextBox1 is on Slide 1:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_LostFocus()
  MsgBox ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes("TextBox1").OLEFormat.Object.Text
End Sub
```

Comment: I pasted your code and updated the correct the slide number. While the code did permit me to type multiple characters, it did not run when I pressed Enter, only when I click in unused space of the presentation (which would be better served if I had them click on a command button to enter/submit the data) and when  I pressed Esc,  But the Esc key closed the presentation after displaying the message box.

Comment: The LostFocus event doesn't fire until you click out of the textbox. And it seems that the textbox "swallows" the Enter key when you press it; the change event doesn't fire, so I'm not sure how you can trap it.